# XML XSLT transformation issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to convert my xml using xslt and it's driving me nuts.

Here is the XML,

```
<env:Body xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<items xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <profiles>
        <candidate_details>
            <application>
                <app_id>ABC</app_id>
                <position_id>RR</position_id>
            </application>
        </candidate_details>
        <candidate_details>
            <application>
                <app_id>ABC2</app_id>
                <position_id>RR2</position_id>
            </application>
        </candidate_details>
    </profiles>
</items>
</env:Body>
```

And here is XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>  
<xsl:template match="env:Body/items/profiles">

    <xsl:for-each select="candidate_details">

            <application>  
                <app_id> <xsl:value-of select='application/app_id' /> </app_id>
            </application>

    </xsl:for-each> 

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is

```
<application>
    <app_id>
        ABC
    </app_id>
</application>
<application>
    <app_id>
        ABC2
    </app_id>
</application>
```

It doesn't print out this format at all, but only the values, what am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks!

PS. I'm aware that

```
<items xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
```

is invalid namespace, but that's how the xml is coming, so I have to use this xml as input.

Comment: Try `<xsl:template match="items/profiles">`, that seems to work at https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Comment: Hi Paul, it doesn't work, it never prints the <app_id>VALUE<app_id> nodes. Only prints ABC and ABC2 as string value.

Comment: Please search for "XSLT default namespace" to find 647 duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things need tweaking

- Add all namespaces explicitly
- Exclude them from the output
- Capture the template at the root element

as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:s="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    exclude-result-prefixes="s env" 
>
<xsl:output  method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/env:Body">
<xsl:for-each select="s:items/s:profiles/s:candidate_details">
<application>
    <app_id>
       <xsl:value-of select='s:application/s:app_id' /> 
    </app_id>
</application>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```